# Search value in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a little function which allows to search values through rows, but there is a problem with it - search function is not working properly.

Please take a look at the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4f3WF/

Try to set text in input to "798" for example.

In the end this function must be able to search through entire row, not just only first or last `ms-column` div. I just don't get what's wrong.

Comment: maybe try a simple :contains selector and use a .parent() on that elements that match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
e.find('.multiple-selector-table .ms-search-label .ms-search').on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    e.find('.multiple-selector-table-row').hide();
    e.find('.ms-column:contains("' + value + '")').parents('.multiple-selector-table-row').show();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f3WF/2/)

In the first step, we hide all rows. Next we search for cells that contain value passed in input and show their parent rows.